# python opencv i have an issue with the counter

Tags: python, algorithm

I am doing a human counting project using opencv. My problem is the counter method counts the object twice when the cx value is between the offset and line_value and offset value. Actually this is not a problem, program has to do it but i want to solve it by giving the cx coordinate specific id for the program to count it only once in between line_value and offset. Can anyone give me an idea on how to do it or does anyone have any other opinion on how to solve the problem. My whole code is below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from time import sleep

video = cv2.VideoCapture(r"C:\Users\korha\OneDrive\Belgeler\Human Detection 1.0\videos\cut1.mp4")
fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
offset = 12
line_value = 230
kernl = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
cx=cy=0
temp_lst = []
rl_lst = []
counter = 0
count_left = 0
count_right = 0

def counter_method():
    global counter
    global count_left
    global count_right  

    if cx != 0:
        temp_lst.append(cx)
        if len(temp_lst) == 1:
            for i in temp_lst:
                rl_lst.append(i)
        if cx > (line_value - offset) and cx < (line_value + offset):
            if cx > rl_lst[0]:
                count_right += 1
                counter += 1
                cv2.line(frame,(start_point),(end_point),(255,0,0),4)
            else:
                count_left += 1
                counter += 1
                cv2.line(frame,(start_point),(end_point),(255,0,0),4)
    
    
def line_method():
    cv2.putText(frame,str(count_right),(205,30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.putText(frame,str(count_left),(190,60),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(255,0,0),2)   
    cv2.putText(frame,'Count right:',(10,30),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.putText(frame,'Count left:',(10,60),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,1,(255,0,0),2)

def rect_method():
    global circle
    global cx
    global cy
    
    if len(contours) != 0:
        for contour in contours:
            if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 50000:
                x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),3)
                x1 = w/2
                y1 = h/2
                cx = x+x1       
                cy = y+y1
                circle = cv2.circle(frame,(int(cx),int(cy)),1,(0,0,255),2)

def main():
    global contours
    global frame
    global start_point
    global end_point
    global ret

    while True:
        ret,frame = video.read()
        if ret is True:
            fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)
            fgmask = cv2.erode(fgmask,kernel = kernl,iterations=1)
            fgmask = cv2.dilate(fgmask,kernel = kernl,iterations=1)
            fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernl)
            fgmask = cv2.morphologyEx(fgmask,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernl)

            contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
            start_point = (line_value,50)
            end_point = (line_value,800)
            line = cv2.line(frame,(start_point),(end_point),(0,0,255),2)
            counter_method()
            line_method()
            rect_method()
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
        elif ret is False:
            video.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

main()
```

And below is the counter_method part:

```
def counter_method():
    global counter
    global count_left
    global count_right  

    if cx != 0:
        temp_lst.append(cx)
        if len(temp_lst) == 1:
            for i in temp_lst:
                rl_lst.append(i)
        if cx > (line_value - offset) and cx < (line_value + offset):
            if cx > rl_lst[0]:
                count_right += 1
                counter += 1
                cv2.line(frame,(start_point),(end_point),(255,0,0),4)
            else:
                count_left += 1
                counter += 1
                cv2.line(frame,(start_point),(end_point),(255,0,0),4)
```

I do not have an idea on an algorithm to solve it. Thanks for help

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BlueRobin my question is clear. I shared the wholde code just for you to understand what i am trying to do

Comment: Yes, it is clear. However, it takes a while to read code, so it’s recommended that you cut out as much as possible.

Comment: all the OpenCV functions work without issue, right? -- no, your question isn't all that clear. your first two sentences already suppose that the reader knows and understands your code (you talk about specific variables like they're known). you need to make an effort to explain the code.

Comment: My problem is the method called 'counter_method' is not doing the counting correctly. The reason that i am saying this is, it can count the object detected twice in between 'line_value' and 'offset'. So i am trying to give a unique value to detected object for the method to detect the object is counted and not count it again for the second or third time.

Comment: ok so you're trying to build _tracking_ from _detections_, which means you need to actually have objects (their positions anyway), and then associate detections to existing objects, or create new objects, or delete old objects that haven't been given a detection. then you can properly handle appearing and disappearing objects.